# Best way to enumerate through all bindings?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I'm wondering if there's a neat built-in way to go through all bindings on a particular form / control?

I would've thought that `myBindingSource.CurrencyManager.Bindings` would fit the bill, but that collection's empty even after using `myBindingSource` in 10+ databindings.

Alternately, if there's a way I can use `myBindingSource` or something else to lookup `Controls` based on the property bound to.

It's not so bad putting all my bindings in one of my own collections, just wondering if there is a way this is already stored.

Comment: what bindings are you talking about?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @Jodrell Windows Forms bindings.

Comment: @DonA In order to find out which control is bound to a property--during final business rule validation (which is kept in a separate project in our system architecture), we check the data then if checks fail we focus the control where that data came from.  Previously we had passed a string of the control name to the `ControlsCollection` which is naturally icky and causes exceptions.

Comment: Did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018554/how-do-i-loop-through-databindings-to-add-control-parse-and-control-format

Comment: @Neolisk I read that, I was hoping there was a better way than iterating through all `Controls` and going through all each of their `DataBindings` collections though.

Comment: Are you assigning DataBindings at runtime? If yes, you could as well save them as you go, for future use.